# Removing portion of QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I am pretty new to Qt. I have QMainWindow over which, a popup dialog will be displayed. Now my requirement is to remove some portion of popup dialog, which means, the contents of the main window should be visible in that particular region of popup dialog.

Does Wt allows such thing..?
Any guidance will be appreciated

Comment: What are the target platforms? Any solution depends on support from the windowing system/compositor used.

Answer (score 0):

you can install a opacity effect over all you widgets

```
QGraphicsOpacityEffect * effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(widget);
effect->setOpacity(0.5);
widget->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

but you can also hide the widget but retaining the space occupied by the widget:

```
QSizePolicy sp_retain = widget->sizePolicy();
sp_retain.setRetainSizeWhenHidden(true);
widget->setSizePolicy(sp_retain);
widget->hide();
```